# Tensorflow dataset crashing VsCode

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

So I'm trying to make a simple image classifier using a CNN and an already labeled data set called "places 365". However, whenever I run `model.fit()` my RAM usage maxes out and vsCode crashes or I restart the kernel.

In the past, I have gotten `model.fit()` to work just fine when I imported the cifar10 dataset for a previous model with `tensorflow.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()`
so I am pretty sure I am missing something with how `tfds.load()` formats the dataset.

Here is my entire setup:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'places365_small',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

def normalize_img(image, label , filename = ''):
  """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label

ds_train = ds_train.map(
    normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds_test = ds_test.map(
    normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_test.cache()
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(365))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=ds_test,
)
```

I essentially followed the instructions here: [Official TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example)

All I really changed was:

- loaded places365_small dataset instead of minst
- added the filename arg to normalize_img since the dataset has 3 features (image, label, filename)
- implemented CNN model

  - changed input shape to match image dimensions for place365
  - final dense layer changed to 365 (365 categories)

Everything else is the same, and all code blocks compile and run in jupyter except for model.fit() so I have no idea why this stupid function is just gobbling my RAM and crashing VsCode. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It could be that the images in Places365 are larger than CIFAR, and so take up more memory. Perhaps try a lower batch size.

Comment: from the docs `The Places365-Standard dataset contains 1.8 million train images` 1.8 MILLION, it is reasonable that you are crashing, try using a subsection of this dataset

Comment: Or you can try a streamable dataset and/or downsampling the images

Comment: @Caridorc was right, I was just loading in way too many images for my test and train dataset. Thank you so much!